# libc++ vs libstdc++ std::is_move_assignable: Which is the most correct?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, libstdc++, libc++

I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of C++ by reading the C++14 standard along with the source of libc++ and libstdc++. The implementation of various `type_traits` items varies between the two, particularly `is_move_assignable`, and I'm trying to figure out which of them is "more correct."

libc++:

```
template <class _Tp> struct is_move_assignable
    : public is_assignable<typename add_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::type,
                           const typename add_rvalue_reference<_Tp>::type> {};
```

libstdc++:

```
template<typename _Tp, bool = __is_referenceable<_Tp>::value>
  struct __is_move_assignable_impl;

template<typename _Tp>
  struct __is_move_assignable_impl<_Tp, false>
  : public false_type { };

template<typename _Tp>
  struct __is_move_assignable_impl<_Tp, true>
  : public is_assignable<_Tp&, _Tp&&>
  { };

template<typename _Tp>
  struct is_move_assignable
  : public __is_move_assignable_impl<_Tp>
  { };
```

The standard states:

> For a referenceable type `T`, the same result as `is_assignable<T&, T&&>::value`, otherwise `false`.

The first thing I noted is that libc++ applies `const` to the second template parameter, which doesn't seem right since the move assignment operator takes a non-const rvalue. libstdc++ also uses `__is_referenceable`, which follows the wording of the standard, but libc++ doesn't. Is that requirement covered by libc++'s use of `add_lvalue_reference` and `add_rvalue_reference`, which both enforce `__is_referenceable` on their own?

I would really appreciate any insight into why each project chose their solutions!

Comment: For anything referenceable, that `const` is meaningless (cv-qualifiers are ignored when applied to a reference type).

Comment: @T.C. Thanks! Any idea why the authors might have added `const`, then?

Comment: It's not often you can get a response time like this: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/a75b75f514c5c92c8ad8d304b76a01a979b6134c :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anything referenceable, the two implementations do the same thing, since the extraneous `const` in libc++ is meaningless but also harmless.

(Judging from the diff, it certainly looks like temporary insanity to me :) Seems to be a C&P issue from a (wrong) implementation of `is_copy_assignable`.)

For anything non-referenceable (i.e., cv `void` or abominable function types), libstdc++ returns `false_type`.

In libc++, `add_{l,r}value_reference` returns it unchanged (this depends on an issue resolution that postdates C++14). Sprinkling a `const` on top does nothing for AFTs and adds a `const` for the `void`y types.

We then go to `is_assignable`, which SFINAE-tests the well-formedness of `declval<T>() = declval<U>()`, for either `T == U == some AFT` or `T == some void type` and `U = some const-qualified void type`. In all cases the expression is ill-formed (in a SFINAE-friendly manner), so we get `false_type` back.

The two are equivalent.

Answer (score 8):

> Thanks! Any idea why the authors might have added `const`, then?

My best guess is temporary (hopefully) insanity:

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/commit/6063ec176d5056683d6ddd310c2e3a8f1c7e1b46#diff-48f5ee43879b5ad38888f0a6ead10113R1245

;-)

I removed the `const` and ran the current unit tests and nothing failed.

Answer (score 5):

`__is_referenceable` is a non-standard, internal libstdc++ routine.  (That doesn't mean it's bad, just that I wouldn't expect libc++ to use it).   Also, the "is referenceable" concept came along much later than `is_move_assignable`.

The `__is_referenceable` helps when dealing with "abominable functions"; things like `int (*) (double) &&`.

Looks like I need to write more tests :-)

Comment: libc++ actually does define `__is_referenceable` for the implementation of `add_lvalue_reference` and `add_rvalue_reference`, but I wasn't sure if applying `__is_referenceable` "implicitly" through the use of `add_rvalue_reference` would always yield the same behavior as libstdc++'s explicit use of `__is_referenceable`. Sorry if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: That `(*)` shouldn't be there :)